# Accessing data bound attributes without using the 'this.attributeName' notation in Polymer

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer

I'm attempting to use sweetalert2 with custom html that contains polymer elements with data binding that I would like to access but I can't get the data using the 'this.attributeName' notation. I think it is due to the sweet alert being attached to the DOM above the element the alert is being created in but I could be wrong is there a workaround to this? I've provided the code for creating the alert and in the resolve is what I've tried to get around this.

```
            swal({
                title: 'Blah Blah',
                html: 
                '<some-el id="days" chosen-days="{{newCDays}}"></some-el>\
                <time-input id="start" time$="{{newSTime}}" hour12 clamp="seconds"></time-input>\
                <time-input id="end" time$="{{newETime}}" hour12 clamp="seconds"></time-input>',
                confirmButtonText: 'Done',
                preConfirm: function() {
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        resolve({
                            days: document.getElementById('days').getAttribute("chosen-days"),
                            start: document.getElementById('start').value,
                            end: document.getElementById('end').time,
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: You should be able to access the property with `document.getElementById('days').chosenDays`. See [demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/QQOqMY?editors=1010). Have you verified that the element definitions has been imported before you use `swal`?

Comment: So 'document.getElementById('days').chosenDays' gives me undefined and 'document.getElementById('days').newCDays' gives me an error saying "property-accessors.html:259 Polymer::Attributes: couldn't decode Array as JSON: {{newCDays}}". I assume the element definitions are there because I can see the html elements, this is all contained within a polymer element that is a view, not sure if that helps.

Comment: Can you create a repro in codepen?

Comment: https://codepen.io/loganxdev/pen/gvXXGN does this help? You can see the binding I put in the sweet alert function under the html property just shows up in the input as a string rather than creating the binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### No data bindings in swal html

Polymer data bindings only work inside a Polymer template, so using that syntax in the `html` field of `swal` would result in literal values being assigned to a property. In the following example, `<paper-input>.value` is set to `"{{myValue}}"` literally (including the curly brackets). Note it does not create `<paper-input>.myValue`.

```
swal({
  html: '<paper-input no-label-float value="{{myValue}}"></paper-input>'
  ...
})
```

The `html` should not contain data bindings. It should look like this:

```
swal({
  html: '<paper-input no-label-float></paper-input>'
  ...
})
```

#### Accessing element properties

In the `preConfirm` function, you could query the element from the `html` field, and access that element's properties by name:

```
swal({
  preConfirm: async () => {
    console.log({
      noLabelFloat: document.getElementById('myInput').noLabelFloat
    });
  }
  ...
})
```

#### Native event binding

In your [Codepen](https://codepen.io/loganxdev/pen/gvXXGN?editors=1010), you show that an `<input>` is used like this:

```
<input type="text" value$="{{testAttr}}">
```

Based on your bindings in `swal`'s `html`, I think you're assuming the data binding above would set `<x-foo>.testAttr` to `<input>.value`, but that's actually not correct. Given a native `<input>` element, you'd have to use Polymer's [native event-binding syntax](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#native-binding):

```
<input type="text" value="{{testAttr::input}}">
```

That sets `<x-foo>.testAttr` to `<input>.value` when the `<input>` raises the `input` event. It's equivalent to:

```
// in x-foo script
myNativeInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
  this.testAttr = myNativeInput.value;
});
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/WMXdQj?editors=1011)

Comment: Spaced out on how to bind with non polymer elements in that codepen, but  everything works perfectly now, thanks.